# Uploading iPad app with the same iPhone app name to the Appstore

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store

guys.
I've a iPhone app on the AppStore.
I am going to upload iPad version(not universal) to the Appstore.
Should I create a new app id?
I would like to use same app name.
But I cannot create a new app with the same app name on the iTunes Connect.
Help me. Any advices are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application name given in iTunes connect must be unique! The `CFBundleDisplay` (Name under the icon) name can then exists multiple time.

You will need to fine another name or do in "universal".

Normaly people add "HD" after the standard name for iPad apps. Example "[AppName] HD"

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
I cannot find iPad app name on my iPhone device.
So I guess there is a possibility with iPad app and iPhone app have same name. Did I have wrong idea?

Comment: Why you searching for iPad app name on your iPhone device? I do not understand your comment?

Comment: What I mean is iPad app names are different group with iPhone app names on the appstore.
So I guess iPad app and iPhone app could have a same name.

Comment: And one question.
If I have iPad app on the appstore, and it's app name is "[AppName]",
how do I name iPhone app?

Comment: Just by adding a new app in iTunes Connect and set a name. Or do you mean something different?